# Filtering on a foreign key of a many to many field in django?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, intersection

I have a set of django models that looks something like this:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    attributes

class Package(AuditBaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class ProfilePackage(AuditBaseModel):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name="profile_packages", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    package = models.ForeignKey(Package, related_name="profile_packages", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

What I need is way to filter on the package name from the profile.  I know I can do something like

```
ProfilePackage.objects.filter(active=True, package__name="Professional").select_related("profile")
```

and that will give me a queryset that includes profiles with that package, but I need to combine this with other filters and I would prefer that profiles model be the top level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your models, this should be fairly easy.

```
Profile.objects.filter(profile_packages__active=True, profile_packages__package__name="Professional")
```

Comment: you nailed it, thank you.  Syntax was tripping me up